# Get Twitter user email using Fabric SDK

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm logging in with twitter using Fabric.

This is how I fetch the user data:

```
loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                    // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
                    AccountService ac = Twitter.getApiClient(result.data).getAccountService();
                    ac.verifyCredentials(true, true, new Callback<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(Result<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User> result) {
                            String imageUrl = result.data.profileImageUrl;
                            String email = result.data.email;
                            String userName = result.data.name;
                            System.out.println(imageUrl);
                            System.out.println(email);
                            System.out.println(userName);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(TwitterException e) {

                        }
                    });

                }
```

This is working fine, except that the `email` variable is `null` when I print to log. Is there an other way of fetching the user email?

Comment: Will you solve this issue? get Email Address? I Am also fetching same issue.

Answer (score 2):

-Here is the Solution!

```
twitauthobj.requestEmail(twitsessionobj,new Callback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<String> stringResult) {
                        'You code here'

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException e) {

                    }
                });
```

-Thanks let me inform if t doesnt work!

Comment: It requires developer to request for email access. Can you specify how to do so?

Comment: Look at this link https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/request-email 

This will start the ShareEmailActivity and display the following screen to the user.

If the user grants access and the email address is available, the success method is called with the email address in the result.

Comment: First line at link is: "Requesting a user’s email address requires your application to be whitelisted by Twitter.". I am not able to find how to get app whitelisted by twitter.

Comment: @seema , I got the same error to get email address. Did you figure out the solution? Could you please share it?

Comment: No, I was just doing it for learning purpose. I got busy, so dropped it there.

Comment: @SufiKhan  You have to get your app whitelisted for that  
GO on their form link https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform and check the "I have an API policy question not covered by these points" option. 
They will respond a few days after and will ask for more information about the application and its app ID. I 

So after several (a lot) emails with support@fabric.io and a few bugs You will get whitelisted.

Comment: I tried this so hard but I can not make these guys whitelist my app. When you start an app from Twitter website, it is easy. But for the apps you create from Fabric, the Twitter support team gets confused I guess. At the end: We were unable to put Twitter support to our app..

Comment: THIS SOLUTION NOT WORKED TO GET EMAIL.

Answer (score 0):

To bypass Twitter's useless request email activity and to fix a leak, I dug through the source code and pulled this out:

```
new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(getClient(sessionResult))
        .baseUrl(new TwitterApi().getBaseHostUrl())
        .addConverterFactory(getFactory())
        .build()
        .create(EmailService.class)
        .getEmail()
        .enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<User> result) {
                String email = result.data.email;
                // Handle the result
                if (email == null) {
                    TwitterProvider.this.failure(
                            new TwitterException("Your application may not have access to"
                                                         + " email addresses or the user may not have an email address. To request"
                                                         + " access, please visit https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform."));
                } else if (email.equals("")) {
                    TwitterProvider.this.failure(
                            new TwitterException("This user does not have an email address."));
                } else {
                    mCallbackObject.onSuccess(createIdpResponse(sessionResult.data, email));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                TwitterProvider.this.failure(exception);
            }
        });

private OkHttpClient getClient(Result<TwitterSession> sessionResult) {
    return OkHttpClientHelper.getOkHttpClient(
            sessionResult.data,
            TwitterCore.getInstance().getAuthConfig(),
            TwitterCore.getInstance().getSSLSocketFactory());
}

private GsonConverterFactory getFactory() {
    return GsonConverterFactory.create(
            new GsonBuilder()
                    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new SafeListAdapter())
                    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new SafeMapAdapter())
                    .registerTypeAdapter(BindingValues.class, new BindingValuesAdapter())
                    .create());
}
```

`EmailService`:

```
interface EmailService {
    @GET("/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true?include_entities=true?skip_status=true")
    Call<User> getEmail();
}
```